# Entity Framework: passing if (count) and adding too much records

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm implementing a web service which is simply adding new record and I want to limit the number of records per user to 10.

```
        var linksCount = _context.Quicklinks.Count(q => q.UserId == _principalInfo.UserId);
        if (linksCount < 10)
        {
            _context.Quicklinks.Add(newItem);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return newItem;
        }
```

When there are many request in short period of time, service is passing the if statement and it's adding new records even if the number is actually greater than 10. Is there a chance to fix this issue without locking this fragment of code?

Comment: Is it possible that caching is happening?

Comment: @JonS No - think of two quick requests.  Both execute `var linksCount ... if (linksCount < 10)` at the same time, both see 9 and go into the `if`.  Both then add `newItem`, and you end up with 11.

Comment: You'll need locking of some sort to fix this, whether it's within your c# code, or you write some custom SQL to perform the add, it'll still do row/table locking.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I see now. He'll probably need locking. He could also store a session variable for quick access and then check that, but locking is the better solution.

Answer (score -1):

As @JamesThorpe said, locking is probably your best bet. If you're finding that locking is too expensive, you could try maintaining a session variable with the number of links and checking that.